# I am using Magento but not able to download it on windows 7

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, magento-community

I am not able to download it on windows 7 on Wamp server but it easily downloaded on Linux.

**What can I do to download it on windows 7?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to Magento SE! You can download Magento at https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/. This should be the same for Windows as for Linux. Perhaps you mean you don't know how to install it on Windows? Your question is very unclear. What did you try so far? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can download Magento for Windows 7 by going to the following link.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/

1. Under "Full Release" you can select the compressed format you would like to download. After selecting, click the download button.
2. After the file is downloaded, extract it's contents to your WAMP `www` directory.
3. Create a database as you will need one for the installation of magento.
4. You can now open the Magento page in your browser through WAMP and install Magento using the on screen instructions.

Hope that helped! :)